# PyAV not installed error but it's installed (GoogleColab)

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to import the ucf101 dataset using

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ucf101', annotation_path='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ucfTrainTestlist', frames_per_clip=16, step_between_clips=1, frame_rate=None, fold=1, train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),]))
```

but it gives me this error

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2c7f10121439> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ucf101', annotation_path='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ucfTrainTestlist', frames_per_clip=16, step_between_clips=1, frame_rate=None, fold=1, train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),]))

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/ucf101.py in __init__(self, root, annotation_path, frames_per_clip, step_between_clips, frame_rate, fold, train, transform, _precomputed_metadata, num_workers, _video_width, _video_height, _video_min_dimension, _audio_samples)
     70             _video_height=_video_height,
     71             _video_min_dimension=_video_min_dimension,
---> 72             _audio_samples=_audio_samples,
     73         )
     74         self.video_clips_metadata = video_clips.metadata

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py in __init__(self, video_paths, clip_length_in_frames, frames_between_clips, frame_rate, _precomputed_metadata, num_workers, _video_width, _video_height, _video_min_dimension, _video_max_dimension, _audio_samples, _audio_channels)
    116 
    117         if _precomputed_metadata is None:
--> 118             self._compute_frame_pts()
    119         else:
    120             self._init_from_metadata(_precomputed_metadata)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py in _compute_frame_pts(self)
    140 
    141         with tqdm(total=len(dl)) as pbar:
--> 142             for batch in dl:
    143                 pbar.update(1)
    144                 clips, fps = list(zip(*batch))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    343 
    344     def __next__(self):
--> 345         data = self._next_data()
    346         self._num_yielded += 1
    347         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    854             else:
    855                 del self._task_info[idx]
--> 856                 return self._process_data(data)
    857 
    858     def _try_put_index(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _process_data(self, data)
    879         self._try_put_index()
    880         if isinstance(data, ExceptionWrapper):
--> 881             data.reraise()
    882         return data
    883 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
    393             # (https://bugs.python.org/issue2651), so we work around it.
    394             msg = KeyErrorMessage(msg)
--> 395         raise self.exc_type(msg)

ImportError: Caught ImportError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    return read_video_timestamps(self.x[idx])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 318, in read_video_timestamps
    _check_av_available()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 40, in _check_av_available
    raise av
ImportError: PyAV is not installed, and is necessary for the video operations in torchvision.
See https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV#installation for instructions on how to
install PyAV on your system.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that I have already installed and imported pyAV a few cells above

```
pip install av
import av
print (av.__version__)
>>8.0.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you install av with

```
!pip install av
```

You need to restart runtime first.

```
MENU > Runtime > Restart runtime
```

Then call your code again

```
import torchvision
dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is confused about this problem also on kaggle, resetting the session would not help (at least tested there) because it will remove all progress from installing PyAV.

The correct solution is to first `!pip install av` and then perform any imports like `import torchvision`. No session resetting is required.

I suspect (but am too lazy to check) the reason is that the availability of PyAV is verified at an earlier stage from `torchvision`.